# Object showing in outliner cannot be found in view port

Tags: objects, armature

I built up the character and rigged it, but while I was adjusting the weight painting, the armature disappeared. I already tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> and the eye icon but I still couldn't find the bone. [Here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qAwsBQ-JA_fMbk_Zg9awgzELgF57hcoj/view?usp=drive_link), and the armature I'm looking for is `Armature.001`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hid them accidentally when you were in *Pose Mode*. First go into *Pose Mode*. Click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide the armature. And then return to *Object Mode*. Since the visibility in *Object Mode* and *Pose Mode* is different in the case bones and meshes (in which you can hide things in *Edit Mode* but things go back to what they were in the object), the ones which you hide in *Pose Mode* stay hidden in *Object Mode* too.

Comment: Yesssss!! It finally showed up!!!! Thank you so much.